# vuex load subcomponents on store state mutation

Tags: vuejs2, state, store, vuex

I use vuex to track the state of my grid-list switcher button. 
Every time as a view type is selected I want to switch between templates but this does not work in my case. Here is the template

```
<div class="users-container">
    <div v-if="$store.state.view === 'list'">
        <h5>list</h5>
         <data-table :columns="columns" ajax="/api/v1/users/datatable"></data-table>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <h5>grid</h5>
        <data-grid :roles = "roles"></data-grid>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I check the state everything updates perfectly but the switch won't happen. What I'm doing wrong in this case?

Comment: You should try to use a computed property instead of binding the store value in the template, as shown in the Vuex guide : https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `computed` property to watch the changes of the state instead.

```js
Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    view: 'list'
  },
  mutations: {
    CHANGE_VIEW (state, type) {
      state.view = type
    },
  }
});

Vue.component('list-view', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h5>List</h5>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="item in dummyData">{{item}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      dummyData: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('grid-view', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h5>Grid</h5>
      <table>
        <tr v-for="item in dummyData"><td>{{item}}</td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      dummyData: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
  }
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data: {
    dummyData: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  },
  computed: {
    view() { return this.$store.state.view }
  },
  methods: {
    changeView(type) {
      this.$store.commit('CHANGE_VIEW', type)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div class="control">
    <p>Change to:</p> 
    <button v-on:click="changeView('list')">List</button>
    <button v-on:click="changeView('grid')">Grid</button>
  </div>
  <div class="users-container">
    <div v-if="view === 'list'">
      <list-view></list-view>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <grid-view></grid-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for feedback, the problem that the 2 components are rendered from different sources and they have own templates to render

Comment: The two components as in the `data-table` and `data-grid`? @fefe

Comment: yes, end each one as it mounts fires ajax to fetch data

Comment: I don't think it has sth to do with the components, I already edited the snippet to use two components to demonstrate. I may be wrong, so more info may be nice. @fefe

Comment: thanks for the update. Yes it seems to be component related the problem. From grid to list I can switch without any problem. Than from list to grid stops to work. My data-table component uses jquery datatables and won't destroy itself on view change

Comment: Okay, have you tried using `v-show` or `v-hide` instead of `v-if`??